# Running a script created in Notepad (Windows) on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, windows, scripts, encoding

I created a Notepad file on Windows and copied it to Ubuntu. The file contains some iptables rules. After making the file executable using `chmod +x` and executing it, it didn't work.

However, when I created a Ubuntu ([gedit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedit)) file and copied the same contents from the Notepad file, made it executable and ran it, it worked.

What should I do to make the Notepad file run on Ubuntu?

Comment: related: [Convert CRLF's to line feeds on Linux](http://superuser.com/q/52044/13868)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Windows and Linux have different end-of-line symbols.

You can install the `dos2unix` utility that fixes it:

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

Run it this way:

```
dos2unix -n winfile.txt linuxfile.txt
```

There is also the `unix2dos` utility.

The Windows-to-Linux conversion can also be done without installing any special software by

```
 tr -d '\r' < winfile.txt > linuxfile.txt
```

***Note:*** *Input and output files must be different.*

A **sed** version will edit the file "in place":

```
 sed  -i 's/\r//g' file.txt
```

Or write to another file:

```
 sed 's/\r//g' winfile.txt > linuxfile.txt
```

Comment: Your command is wrong. `dos2unix winfile.txt linuxfile.txt` tries to convert both files. Use this command `dos2unix -n winfile.txt linuxfile.txt`

Comment: @A.B. Fixed. You are right. They changed input parameters. I did not use it for a long time.

Comment: Anyway, good answer +1

Comment: Thank you all very much. Since I don't have Notepad++ and I didn't want to install a new package (dos2unix), I preferred the "tr" command. I tried it and it worked. But please note that the source and destination files must be different.

Comment: @Albert Added to the answer. It can be done another way to keep the file name, but it is not worth the effort IMHO. And it is better to have different names anyway not to mix files up.

Comment: @Albert Added sed version to edit file in place.

Comment: Also, sidenote:Window's files don't understand unix permissions.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows, you need to change the End of Line (EOL) format in Notepad++ to UNIX:

[image]

That way it will work on Ubuntu too.

Comment: That way it will work _only_ on Ubuntu/Linux. While special advanced editors like Notepad++ might recognize the line ending type and display it correctly anyway, normal Windows notepad etc. won't.

Comment: @ByteCommander YES, but he wants to get it run on Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, of course. I know and upvoted therefore. I just wanted to make this fact clear, so that nobody will be surprised when the file now looks strange in normal notepad.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I read again his question, I do not think I misunderstood and my answer is one of the good solutions to his problem.

Answer (score 2):

Windows uses CR+LF for line breaks. In Linux/Unix you need LF. Therefore you have to replace CR+LF into LF in your script:

Install `dos2unix`

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

And correct your script via

```
dos2unix <your_script_file>
```

or via

```
dos2unix -n <your_script_file> <out_file>
```

if you need a different output file

<sub>More informations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)</sub>

---

from `man dos2unix`

```
NAME
       dos2unix - DOS/Mac to Unix and vice versa text file format converter

SYNOPSIS
           dos2unix [options] [FILE ...] [-n INFILE OUTFILE ...]
           unix2dos [options] [FILE ...] [-n INFILE OUTFILE ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

I use cygwin on Windows.
Open the file with vi. Then enter

```
:set ff=unix<enter> followed by 
:wq<enter>
```

will save the file with Unix end of line characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -bsc '%s/\r//|x' file
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `\r` carriage return
4. `x` save and close