# my ubuntu shows shell script echo in strange way

Tags: command-line, sh, echo

Hi I have a file with shell script which looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash 
todayDate=$(date)
echo "Today's date is  ${todayDate}. have a nice weekend!"
```

but when I call this file in my ubuntu terminal, I get such result

```
. have a nice weekend!eb 12 22:29:00 CET 2022
```

Why doesn't it show

```
Today's date is Sat Feb 12 22:31:55 CET 2022. have a nice weekend!
```

??
The image below is evidence that ubuntu shows weird echo in terminal

[image]

Someone asked me to upload result of ls -alh. This is the result

```
total 0
drwx------ 1 username username 512 Feb 12 22:07
drwx------ 1 username username 512 Feb 12 21:57
-rwx------ 1 username username 77  Feb 12 22:41 4Bbash
```

image version:
[image]

Comment: might be your file has Windows Line endings?

Comment: @pLumo actually I don't know what is Windows Line endings .. I just coded and trying to run file

Comment: How did you run this? Can you append command output of ```ls -alh``` in that folder which contains this script?

Comment: @MerajulArefinPial I posted my ls -alh result.

Comment: did @pLumo 's solution worked?

Comment: @MerajulArefinPial I am trying to find way how to change windows line endings to unix line endings in notepad..

Comment: I don't think Notepad can do that, use a proper text editor, not such crappy software e.g. Notepad++ or VSCode or so.

Comment: @pLumo that's sad. Ok then I will try to download notepad++

Comment: Ask Microsoft why their software is still the same crap as 30 years ago.

Comment: See here for notepad++ https://askubuntu.com/a/645030/631600

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your file has Windows Line endings `\r\n`.

- `\r` means "Carriage return" (go back to beginnging of line)
- `\n` means "Line feed" (go to next line).

Unix uses only `\n` as line ending.

Thus, your variable `todayDate` will include a `\r` at the end. This will place the cursor back to first position, and the text after it overwrites the previous text.

Set your text editor to use Unix Line Endings (Line Feed) or use `dos2unix` to fix your file. Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803162/how-to-change-windows-line-ending-to-unix-version) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645027/running-a-script-created-in-notepad-windows-on-ubuntu).